# one edge with different bevel

Tags: edges, bevel

I have an edge with different bevel (smooth).
The picture shows the marked edge is start smooth and changed in a hard edge.
How can I fix this edge to a smooth edge like in the front?

Thank you

[image: the edge start with a smooth bevel and then it change to a hard bevel].

Comment: Hello, your question is not clear, do you mean you've used a Bevel modifier? If my answer is not correct please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without the file.

Probably your edges look smooth because you must have enabled the *Subdivision Surface*'s *On Cage* option, in order to you see the modifier's effect in *Edit* mode. The other ones don't, maybe because the normals are inverted. Try to select all, then *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the solution. It was the second.
The normals were inverted. Now everything is correct.